# How to fill entries in trigger table for already existing entries. - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

This is my schema.

```
table_products - product_id, product_name, product_description, product_image_path, brand_id, available.
table_brands - brand_id, brand_name
table_categories - category_id, category_name
table_product_category_mapping - product_id, category_id
```

Data is already filled in tables.

Now Because of new requirement i want to create a trigger to keep track of count of product in each brand and category. so i created a table:

```
table_product_count - brand_id, category_id, count //under this brand and category these many products are there.
```

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER inc_count AFTER INSERT ON table_products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_product_count SET count = count + 1 WHERE brand_id = NEW.brand_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER inc_count2 AFTER INSERT ON table_products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_product_count SET count = count + 1 WHERE brand_id = NEW.brand_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

How to fill count entries in table_product_count table for which(product) data already entered.

Answer (score 0):

This trigger is working if you have all the brand_id, category_id in table_product_count table:

DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER inc_count AFTER INSERT ON test.table_products FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE table_product_count SET COUNT = COUNT + 1 WHERE brand_id = NEW.brand_id; 
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;